# Como usar Linq em 2 listas para que, uma complemente a outra no C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Olá, tenho a seguinte situação:

```cs
public class Foo {
  int id { get; set; }
  Bar bar { get; set; }
}
public class Bar {
  int id { get; set; }
  int FooId { get; set; }
}
public class Program {
  public static void Main(string[] args){
    var foos = new List<Foo> {
      new Foo{ id: 1 }, new Foo{ id: 2 }, 
      new Foo{ id: 3 }, new Foo{ id: 4 }
    };
    var bars = new List<Bar> {
      new Bar{ id: 5, FooId: 2},
      new Bar{ id: 6, FooId: 4}
    }
  }
}
```

Para que eu possa inserir os `bars` dentro de seus respectivos `foos` eu tenho que usar um foreach para verificar se os itens tem a propriedade `FooId` igual ao id de Foo na lista, assim:

```cs
foreach(var foo in foos)
  foreach(var bar in bars)
    if(bar.FooId == foo.Id)
      foo.Bar = bar;
```

Se eu fosse fazer em Linq, eu teria que gerar um novo objeto e atribuir todas as propriedades do antigo ao novo e, em seguida correlacionar, assim:

```cs
foos = foos
  .Join(bars,foo => foo.Id,bar => bar.FooId, (foo, bar) => new { foo, bar })
  .Select(x=> new Foo{ Id = x.foo.Id, Bar = x.bar })
  .ToList();
```

Existe alguma forma de eu aproveitar o objeto de `foos` sem a necessidade de recriá-lo? A idéia dessa pergunta é porque eu consigo fazer algo semelhante em javascript assim:

```js
var foos = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];
var bars = [{id: 5, fooId: 2}, {id: 6, fooId: 4}];

foos = foos.map(x=> x.bar = bars.filter(y => y.fooId === x.id)[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seus dois exemplos (em c#) não apresentam os mesmos resultados!
O primeiro (com os foreach encadeados) a lista fica com os 4 elementos e o segundo (com o join e select) a lista fica apenas com os 2 elementos em que o `bar` não é `null`

Você pode obter o mesmo resultado assim:

```
foreach (var foo in foos)
    foo.bar = bars.FirstOrDefault(b => b.FooId == foo.id);
```

Na verdade seria `LastOrDefault`..

Ou assim:

```
foos.ForEach(f => f.bar = bars.FirstOrDefault(b => b.FooId == f.id));
```

Ou:

```
foos = foos.Select(f => { f.bar = bars.FirstOrDefault(b => b.FooId == f.id); return f; }).ToList();
```

Para remover os nulos:

```
foos.RemoveAll(f => f.bar == null);
```

Comment: o que preciso é retornar todos os itens, independente se estão nulos ou não

Comment: @LeandroLuk `foos.ForEach(f => f.bar = bars.FirstOrDefault(b => b.FooId == f.id));` não atende sua necessidade? adicionei outro exemplo, mas não é tão eficiente, se busca eficiência a sua solução com `foreach` ou com `for` será a melhor.

Comment: Eu achei que teria alguma forma melhor de usar sem foreach. Afinal o Linq é bem eficiente em muitas situações...